# How to change view in application after get message from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

is there any possibility that after receiving a message from firebase in onMessageReceived (RemoteMessage remoteMessage) (FirebaseMessagingService) reload the current view of the application if it is running ? e.g. I have started MainActivity and I get message from Firebase and I want reload ListView in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) in *onMessageReceived*. For example:

```
 Intent bIntent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
            bIntent.putExtra("keyAction", "yourPushAction");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(bIntent);
```

and can receive broadcast in your activity's *onCreate()* like below:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
```

and the *mMessageReceiver* is as:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("keyAction");
    }
};
```

Don't forget to *unregisterReceiver* in *onDestroy()*

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver);
```